# Robust way to translate animation temporarily, including particules/quick explode

Tags: animation, drivers

How can I robustly move an animation temporarily? When I move the keyframes in the dopesheet, it won't move for instance the particle frame start/end. For instance, I just selected the cube and did "Object > Quick effect > Quick explode", and nothing appears in the dopesheet:

[image]

If it's impossible, is there a workflow that would allow me to solve maybe differently this issue? I guess translating animations is quite common as people rarely know in advance which timing they exactly want...

Comment: @martyfouts: thanks. I'm not used to baking simulations, can you then choose the starting time of included simulation using keyframes? Or do you mean you completely render them in a different project and integrate them in post production? Concerning the drivers, I asked before if it was possible to "drive" a field into a keyframe, but I found no answers, so if you know how to do I'm interested. If you mean to add a driver to another variable, like a custom property, then the benefit is not clear, except maybe to centralize these parameters...

Comment: I deleted all my comments ... there is not an option to set driver or keyframe this value ... that make a sence since variable here will generate mishmatch ... so - no I dont think there is a native way in Blender to solve it. So ... as written before you would have to bake sim to by able namipulate on timeline.